# fig.tight_layout() but plots still overlap

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

Imagine I have some dataset for wines and I find the top 5 wine producing countries:

```py
# Find top 5 wine producing countries.
top_countries = wines_df.groupby('country').size().reset_index(name='n').sort_values('n', ascending=False)[:5]['country'].tolist()
```

Now that I have the values, I attempt to plot the results in 10 plots, 5 rows 2 columns.

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 15))
fig.tight_layout()
i = 0
for c in top_countries:
    c_df = wines_df[wines_df.country == c]
    i +=1
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(5,2,i)
    i +=1
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(5,2,i)
    sns.kdeplot(c_df['points'], ax=ax1)
    ax1.set_title("POINTS OF ALL WINES IN %s, n=%d" % (c.upper(), c_df.shape[0]), fontsize=16)
    sns.boxplot(c_df['price'], ax=ax2)
    ax2.set_title("PRICE OF ALL WINES IN %s, n=%d" % (c.upper(), c_df.shape[0]), fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Even with this result, I still have my subplots overlapping.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Using `python3.6` with `matplotlib==2.2.2`

Comment: Try to move the `tight_layout()` to *after* you do all the plots, i.e. directly before `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Thomas Kühn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587163/fig-tight-layout-but-plots-still-overlap#comment95971649_54587163) said, you have to move `tight_layout()` after doing the plots, like in:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 15))
i = 0
for c in top_countries:
    c_df = wines_df[wines_df.country == c]
    i +=1
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(5,2,i)
    i +=1
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(5,2,i)
    sns.kdeplot(c_df['points'], ax=ax1)
    ax1.set_title("POINTS OF ALL WINES IN %s, n=%d" % (c.upper(), c_df.shape[0]), fontsize=16)
    sns.boxplot(c_df['price'], ax=ax2)
    ax2.set_title("PRICE OF ALL WINES IN %s, n=%d" % (c.upper(), c_df.shape[0]), fontsize=16)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

If it is still overlapping (this may happen in some seldom cases), you can specify the padding with:

```py
fig.tight_layout(pad=0., w_pad=0.3, h_pad=1.0)
```

Where `pad` is the general padding, `w_pad` is the horizontal padding and `h_pad` is the vertical padding. Just try some values until your plot looks nicely. `(pad=0., w_pad=.3, h_pad=.3)` is a good start, if you want to have your plots as tight as possible.

Another possibility is to specify `constrained_layout=True` in the figure:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 15), constrained_layout=True)
```

Now you can delete the line `fig.tight_layout()`.

---

**edit:**
One more thing I stumbled upon:
It seems like you are specifying your `figsize` so that it fits on a standard DIN A4 paper in **centimeters** (typical textwidth: 16cm). But **`figsize` in matplotlib is in inches**. So probably replacing the figsize with `figsize=(16/2.54, 15/2.54)` might be better.

I know that it is absolutely confusing that matplotlib internally uses inches as units, considering that it is mostly the scientific community and data engineers working with matplotlib (and these usually use SI units). As ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed out, there are several discussions going on about how to implement other units than inches.

Comment: It's not that the figsize in cm isn't wanted, it just causes a lot of problems that need to be thought through, such that until now noone was able to develop a clear concept. The latest discussion is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12402) and [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12415).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok, I'm sorry for my misunderstanding. I also want to make clear, that I really really love matplotlib and that I prefer it over all other modules. So this is imho only a tiny disadvantage once you get used to it. Furthermore I understand that it is in many cases the most straight-forward way to deal with DPI of printers, displays etc.

Comment: thank you. also, i'm doing this on jupyter notebook so no printing involved. but that's a good note to take care of